# Computed column through scalar function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question is in relation to [user-defined scalar function to generate computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264633/user-defined-scalar-function-to-generate-computed-column/60264705#60264705)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Installment  
ADD SurchargeCalculated AS 
   (select Amount * Days * InstSurchargePercentage / 365 / 100
    from InstallMentPlan 
    where InstallMentPlan.PlanKey = Installment.PlanKey
   )
GO
```

Error is:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: Scalar functions, however, tend to have a performance hit  (*note, I can't speak for them on computed columns in SQL Server 2019  with it's inlining functionality*) and can cause race conditions. This would seem like a better candidate for a `VIEW` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a computed column: it may reference solely columns from the same table and same row.

As a workaround, you could define a view:

```
create view dbo.InstallmentView as
select 
    i.*,
    (
        select p.Amount * p.Days * p.InstSurchargePercentage / 365 / 100
        from dbo.InstallMentPlan p
        where p.PlanKey = i.PlanKey
    ) SurchargeCalculated 
from  dbo.Installment i
```

This can also be expressed with a `join`:

```
create view dbo.InstallmentView as
select 
    i.*,
    p.Amount * p.Days * p.InstSurchargePercentage / 365 / 100 SurchargeCalculated 
from  dbo.Installment i
left join dbo.InstallMentPlan p on p.PlanKey = i.PlanKey
```

Note that you should enumerate the columns that you want to select form `dbo.Installment` instead of using `*` (I did so only because I have no knowledge of your database structure).

Comment: thank you very much for your reply...it throws this error now...Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InstallmentView, Line 6
Invalid column name 'PlanKey'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InstallmentView, Line 6
Invalid column name 'PlanKey'.

Comment: @khawarabbasi: well, do you have a column called `PlanKey` in tables `dbo.Installment` and `dbo.InstallMentPlan`? I took that from your original query.

Comment: I have these columns in Installment table ,[PlotId]
      ,[MemberId]
      ,[PlotFileId]
      ,[InstallmentNo]
      ,[InstallmentOrder]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[DueDate]
      ,[AmountPaid]
      ,[PaidOn]
      ,[Surcharge]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[ModifiedOn]
      ,[SyncState]
      ,[SurchargePaid]
      ,[SurchargePaidOn]
      ,[PartialInstallmentId]
      ,[InstPlanDetailId]
      ,[days]
      ,[Is_Lumpsum]

Comment: and InstallmentPlan col=> [SizeId]
      ,[PhaseId]
      ,[BlockId]
      ,[PlanName]
      ,[TotalCost]
      ,[DownPayment]
      ,[NoOfInstallment]
      ,[InstallmentAmount]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[ModifiedOn]
      ,[DownPaymentDueDate]
      ,[InstallmentDurationMonth]
      ,[DPSurchargeAmount]
      ,[DPSurchargePercentage]
      ,[InstSurchargeAmount]
      ,[InstSurchargePercentage]
      ,[InstSurchargeDueMonth]
      ,[DueDateAdjustment]
      ,[LumsumDiscount]
      ,[LumsumDiscountDueDate]

Comment: @khawarabbasi: in your original query, there is a column called `PlanKey` in both tables, so I used it as a join condition. If that's not correct, then you need to change that to the relevant columns. I cannot tell which columns can be used (this is your database!).